# PHP JSON Encode From CSV

Tags: php, json

I have a simple script that looks like:

```
$row_to_show = 2;

$handle = fopen('myfile.csv', 'r');
if ($handle !== false) {
    $row_count = 0;
    while($csv_line = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        $row_count++;
        if ($row_count == $row_to_show) {
            $latestResults = ($csv_line);
            echo json_encode($latestResults);
        }
    }
}
```

It grabs the 2nd row in the CSV file. It then encodes it to json like and displays like this:

> ["20-Apr-2013","46","8","34","38","44","42","14","4","MERLIN"]

However, what I'm trying to do is something like:

```
"Date":20-Apr-2013,"ball1":46,"ball2":8,"ball3":34,"ball4":38,"ball5":44"ball6":42,"bonusball":14,"set":4,"machine":MERLIN
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the headers as the first row in the file?

Comment: Look into `array_combine()` to add keys. And do _build_ your array first, and only after the while loop do the `echo json_encode();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, the JSON output would be what I expect from a CSV since a CSV is just an array of values.

If you want to add "column header" information you'll need to create an associative array.

Sometimes, the first line of a CSV contains the header info, if this is the case you can save it for later use:

```
/...
$headers = null;
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    $row_count++;
    // The first row contains the headers, save it
    if($row_count == 1) {
        $headers = $csv_line;
    }
//..
```

If it doesn't, you'll need to create it manually...

```
$headers = array('Date', 'ball1', 'ball2',...);
```

You can then merge them into a single Associative array (see SO question: ["PHP - Merge two arrays (same-length) into one associative?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200885/php-merge-two-arrays-same-length-into-one-associative))

```
if ($row_count == $row_to_show) {
    $latestResults = ($csv_line);
    $output = array_combine($headers, $latestResults);
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

I hope that helps!

*edit*

Thanks to Marios comment (which I saw after I wrote this), it appears the SO question ["CSV to Json with header row as key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712840/csv-to-json-with-header-row-as-key?lq=1) pretty much covers the same thing.