# PHP explode comma separated string into array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, explode

Lets say I have a text field with the following data. Lines starting with `#` are comments. The first line is the column headers and values are comma separated.

```
# some instruction
# some instruction
Day,Open,Close
Monday,09:00,17:00
Tuesday,09:00,18:00
```

How can I explode this to get an array like this:

```
$openingTimes = [
   ['Day' => 'Monday', 'Open' => '09:00', 'Close' => '17:00'],
   ['Day' => 'Tuesday', 'Open' => '09:00', 'Close' => '18:00'],
];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV to Json with header row as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712840/csv-to-json-with-header-row-as-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you first split the text field by a new line, then process each line one at a time.

Ignore anything starting with a `#` (the `$line[0] == '#'` bit).

Use `str_getcsv()` to split the line into separate fields (allowing for quoted fields etc.)  Then if there hasn't been a header so far, then store this split value as the header.  If there has been a header, then add this new data as part of the output, combining it with `array_combine()`...

```
$input = '# some instruction
# some instruction
Day,Open,Close
Monday,09:00,17:00
Tuesday,09:00,18:00';

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $input);
$header = null;
$output = [];
foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    if ( $line[0] == '#' )  {
        continue;
    }
    $data = str_getcsv($line);
    if ( $header == null )  {
        $header = $data;
    }
    else    {
        $output[] = array_combine($header, $data);
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: (I've flagged the question as a dupe.  There must be others?   This is a nice tidy solution to the given problem.  Rather a shame this question doesn't include any workings.  This is a 'cookbook' question.)

Comment: @Progrock the dupe doesn't deal with commented lines and as it assumes the first line is the header will not work with the sample in OP's question.